# Regular expression replace [*

Tags: c#, regex

How to replace the string using regular expression for the following pattern

> [*1. Introduction*]

to

> 1. Introduction

i've replaced it simply 
by

```
string s="[*1. Introduction*]";
s.Replace("[*", string.Empty).Replace("*]", string.Empty);
```

is it any equivalent for this using regular expression in c#.

Comment: Your code would work, you could do it using Regex as well.  Which one would be better would depend on what you wanted to do.  For a simple line of text i would probably go with your code.  If you had a massive document to process i would probably regex it.

Comment: @BenRobinson s.Trim('[', '*'); would also work a treat on the sample string.

Comment: @Gusdor I think it would need to be s.Trim('[', '*', ']') but as you say it would work on "the sample string", if that's all that is required. e.g. an extra space at the beginning or end of the string would break the Trim call but not the replace.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yes, I meant that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes..

```
 Regex.Replace(s,"^\\[\\*|\\*\\]$", string.Empty);
```

Though I recommend you to stick with String's Replace method..

Comment: @ConnellWatkins indeed..Regex would be overkill here..;)

Comment: Regex.Replace is not static Method i think

Comment: @arunkumarnonascii there is a static method for it...I just missed the last parameter..:)

Comment: @arunkumarnonascii [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of using a regular expression for this, would be to assure that it wouldn't replace any `[*` or `*]` that would occur by themselves. The pattern can match the occurance of both.

A limitation of using such a pattern would be that it can't handle nested occurances, e.g. `"Some [*text [*with*] nested*] tags."`.

Performance for using a regular expression compared to `String.Replace` would be about the same. There is some overhead when creating the regular expression, but you need to run through the string twice when you use `String.Replace`.

Using a regular expression would look like this:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[\*(.+)\*\]", "$1");
```

The parentheses in the pattern captures what's within the tags, and `$1` in the replacement string uses what was captured to replace the entire tag.

Answer (score 1):

Like said @BenRobinson, btw I didn't know this :D

```
string s = " [*1. Introduction*] ".Trim(' ', '[', ']', '*');
```